# error al mostrar datos en la tabla

Tags: angular

alguien sabe por que me sale el error del objeto i cuando se lo paso al metodo, se lo quito y se me soluciona pero no me muestra los datos es pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Aqui si me compila pero en la pantalla no me aparece los datos en la pantalla]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: y el component lo tengo asi]

Answer (score 0):

La misma consola te dice le error : "Expected 0 arguments, but got 1", es decir tu funcion no recibe argumentos, debería ser `agregarEmpleado(i: number)`